# Linking google test to your main project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, googletest, .lib

I am new to the gtest. I have followed a tutorial how to set it up in the VS 2105.
But all that I could find talked about how to build and link gtest. 
I am passed that level. The code below runs and passes the first dummy test.

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(VI, simple) {
    EXPECT_EQ(false, false);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

My question:
How do I exactly hook it up to my project that I want to test? 
Both gtest project and my "code" project are in the same solution.
As far as I understood from reading numerous tutorials, I need 2 things:

1) to include my .h of the class I am about to test (easy and done)

2) To compile my "code" project into a static lib and then hook up
   the lib to gtest project so I can create and test objects from the
   "code" project.

I am struggling with the point 2. How exactly do I go about it?

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a new empty Win32 project to your solution, in its properties select Project Type "static library (.lib)"
2. Move all your sources except the `main()` function to that project
3. Add a reference to the .lib project to both your main application project and the google test project

Comment: Is there particular reason for the new project to be WIn32 and not 64 or it does not matter? I compiled both gtest and my project in x64.

Comment: Win32 is the type of the project template in the New Project dialog.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to turn my current "code" project into a static lib and then create a new project just for a main? It seems easier and then coping  all my files. Also my current project is a qt5 template project will that still work with it?

Comment: If you do that you will lose linker settings because a static lib project has librarian settings instead of linker settings. But can be done of course.